# how to go another activity from Preference screen in android

Tags: android

This is my Preference class :

```
customPref
                .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "The custom preference has been clicked",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                                "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference
                                .edit();
                        editor.putString("myCustomPref",
                                "The preference has been clicked");
                        editor.commit();
                        return true;
                    }

                });
```

this able to display data on Toast .

But when  i apply this code

```
customPref
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                    Intent int1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            termandcondition.class);
                    getBaseContext().startActivity(int1);


                    return true;
                }

            });
```

in prefernces then it becomes Error and now displaying data please help me how to Apply to go another activity

this is prefnces.xml file

```
<Preference
        android:key="customPref"
        android:summary="END-USER LICENCE AGREEMENT FOR USING WWW.TAXMANN.COM"
        android:title="Term and Condition"



         />
```

i try from many time now able to do please help me

Comment: Have u declared termandcondition.java in your Androidmaifest.xml file?

Comment: yes dear i did  but mistke is here in prefnces class not moving form currnet to another  while am able to display toast

Comment: Again,, what does the error say? Logcat output.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ft0BRr9u   this is logcat Error

Comment: I noticed you asked the same question yesterday, don't ask the same question twice. You now make people investigate something other people already have done yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `getBaseContext().startActivity()` instead of `startActivity()`. Because of this, you try to start a new activity from outside of an activity context. And like the error says: `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`
So this is probably not really what you want. Android requires you to start the activity's, from within other activity's to maintain the backstack.

Comment: I ll tell You dear But i dont thing ur this code will apply coz i tried it before i ll give u logcat for that

Comment: The activity you are doing this in, is a PreferenceActivity? If not, so the activity is just a 'normal' class, then there is your problem. You either have to pass a activity context in the class constructor, or move this code to a (Preference)Activity class.

Comment: dear after Putting this code http://pastie.org/5514701 Logcat Error is coming  please check

Comment: By reading the logcat output, you can see there is a NullPointerException on line 18 of the onCreate of termandcondition.java. So there is nothing wrong with this part of the code. Removing getBaseContext will solve the problem of not being able to start the activity, but there is another problem in the activity you are starting

Comment: yes yesterday i asked no one replay me plz help me  how to Implement it i i have take on prefcens and i want to move another screen where  i want to display data in web view

Comment: yes i m doing this in Prefnces activity where i have apply setting of application

Comment: Read what I said, and what somebody else also said in the other question yesterday: there is a NullPointerException on line 18 of the onCreate of termandcondition.java. You could accept this answer, and start a new one for this problem, with a copy/paste of the termandcondition class. It is unrelated to this.

Comment: Dear please tell me how to Fix that issue

Comment: webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//18 line numbe
  webView.loadUrl("http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Termsandcondition.html");

Comment: Are you sure the WebView with id=webview1 is in the layout file named termandcondition.xml? Either webView == null, or webView.getSettings()==null. Also you have to add webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); under setJavaScriptEnabled(true);